# Jenkins not running a few protractor tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, protractor

I have a project I’m working on in which I have a set of protractor tests to run and for some reason a few of the tests I have written are not showing up in the allure report Jenkins gives me after running them (1 shows as run, 4 as skipped, and 3 new ones I wrote don’t show up at all). Additionally, it will run one of the tests in that suite and then skip the rest of the tests in the entire project so only about 25% of the tests run, all of which that are run pass.

I have specified the branch in Jenkins and even tried only running the specific describe block by using fdescribe. The tests are not xit. Has anyone ran into something similar?

A somewhat related problem is that I am unable to run any of the protractor tests locally as whenever I try to start or update the webdriver manager I get a timeout error. It could be some sort of proxy issue as I need to be connected to a VPN to run these tests but scripts should be set up to run them and those scripts do not work for me, though they do for other people who have downloaded the projects.

Thanks

Comment: without seeing your code/jenkins setup, I'd recommend you looking at the protractor config and look for problem in how you require specs to run. Doesn't sound like jenkins problem